# Boot selector bit on STM32g030

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I would like to program the STM32G030.

On page 14 of the datasheet it says:

[image: Boot mode in datasheet]

so there is a Boot pin and Boot selector bit. The Boot pin is pin 36 in the LQFP48 package I am using. I cannot however find anything about the Boot selector bit. Can anyone help?

Is the boot selector bit (of which there are 3 boot selector options) is this input into the microcontroller through the single Boot pin?

Comment: For STM32 you need not only datasheet, but also reference manual. It contains a list of registers and what each bit does. Ctrl+F there around (try "boot"). Here you go: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00463896-stm32g0x0-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a physical pin, it is a configuration bit stored in configuration memory area that you have access via the bootloader.